# Oracle copy DB from one windows server to another

Tags: oracle, windows, migration, rman

I am not an Oracle DBA but looking for the best approach to copy/clone an Oracle database from one windows server to another, here is my configuration and my requirements:

**Configuration**
**Server 1 (Source)**
Oracle DB Version: 10.2.0.4
OS: Windows Server 2008 Standard
**Server2 (Destination)**
Oracle DB Version: 11.2.0.3
OS:  Windows Server 2008 Standard
On the destination server, Oracle is installed but no DB is created

**Requirements**
1.  It is preferable that the source DB does not shutdown during the process, I switched to archivelog mode for this purpose
2.  The Source database size is around 200Gb and there is no enough space on the Source server to make an RMAN backup then copy the files to the destination server, I am looking for a way to back up the DB directly on the remote server (destination) but I am not able to do it through RMAN for Enterprise Manager

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a [data pump using a network link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL300) would do the job.  It's always preferable to run it during quieter hours but if your source database is not under powered then you might be able to run it during regular hours without your user's noticing any difference in performance.

From the [article](http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php)

- create a database link from the destination to the source
- grant EXP_FULL_DATABASE on the source database to the user in the link
- grant IMP_FULL_DATABASE on the destination database to the user with the link OR grant DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE role to the destination database user

  impdp test/test@db10g tables=SCOTT.EMP network_link=REMOTE_SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR logfile=impdpSCOTT.log remap_schema=SCOTT:TEST

Things to investigate

- the PARALLEL options which will speed things up.
- any custom tablespaces on the origin database?
- are you going from the same character set to the same character set?
- you do have a development environment to test this..